# Do *Mundi* and *Mundum* mean different things?

Tags: grammar-choice, word-comparison, declension

I came across this expression in the book: *The Invisible Man*, (H.G. Wells)

> Griffin *contra mundum*...with a vengeance

From my *very* basic knowledge of Latin (I'm a Bio. student) I take it that *contra mundum* literally translates to "Against the World".

But a couple of years back, I recall chancing across another expression on some Wikipedia article (I don't rightly remember, but I think it was about some doctor who worked at a Nazi concentration camp), where this man describes the concentration camp to a colleague as:

> *Anum mundi*

And the corresponding Wikipedia translation was "Anus of the world".

I conducted a cursory search online, and from what I gather, both *mundum* and *mundi* mean the same thing.

So, two questions here:

**Q1: Do *mundi* and *mundum* really mean the same thing, i.e- "World"?**

**Q2: Even if they *do* mean the same, can they be *used* in the same circumstances? For example, would there be anything wrong in me using the hybrids: *Contra mundi* or *Anum mundum*?**

---

I mentioned the sources (*Contra mundum*: Britain, 1890s; and *Anum mundi*: Germany, 1940s) just in case that may yield a clue...of sorts.

Comment: **However:** There is another quotation you may come across: ***Mundis omnia munda,***  **'To the pure, all things are pure.'** This *mundus* is a homonym, meaning 'innocent/ untainted.' Cf. the tag Burton places on page one of his 'Arabian Nights.'

Comment: @Hugh I've always known it as *Omnia munda mundis*. But, is *Mundis omnia munda* also acceptable?

Comment: @paracresol : Latin is quite forgiving with regard to word order. These mean the same thing, perhaps with a slight shift in emphasis.

Comment: My search engine is equally forgiving with respect to word order: so Wiki p and five other sites; both versions found.

Comment: Your essay is faultless. I am telling you so in order to pass muster and be cleared for this well-informed group

Comment: Welcome to the site, Edward! What essay are you referring to? If this is a comment on C. M. Weimer's answer (or mine for some reason), it can be converted to an actual comment. Answers on this site are supposed to be used only for answering the original question, in this case roughly "are *mundum* and *mundi* different things?". I recommend taking a look at our [tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: In addition, you do not need clearance for the basic functions of this site, like posing and answering questions. Only commenting and other function do require a (low) number of reputation points that you will quickly accumulate!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are the exact same word, and yes both mean "world" but no you cannot substitute them for each other. Latin is a fully inflexional language, which means that the words have endings which change depending on their grammatical use. You can compare *mundum* and *mundi* to *whom* and *whose*. You wouldn't say, "This is me ball" (well, not in Standard English, at least, but if you want to sound like a pirate...) nor would you say "Give my the ball." This is what we call "declension."

Likewise, *mundum* is the accusative form of *mundus* (the *I* analogue from the above analogies). You use it with the direct object or with certain prepositions (like *contra*). Meanwhile, *mundi* in this case is genitive, which is the case used for possession. It's why we translate it as "of the world" not just "the world."

Similar to English pronouns (or other languages like German, Icelandic, Russian, or Greek), you indeed cannot replace them willy-nilly. Because they encode the grammar along with the meaning, you'd end up with nonsense if you tried.

Answer (score 14):

The Latin word used for "world" here is *mundus*.
This word has several forms (singular/plural):

> nominative: *mundus/mundi*
>   accusative: *mundum/mundos*
>   genitive: *mundi/mundorum*
>   dative: *mundo/mundis*
>   ablative: *mundo/mundis*

The five grammatical cases are used in different contexts and they are rarely interchangeable.
Two examples:
"Of the world" requires the singular genitive *mundi*.
The preposition *contra* requires that the following word is in accusative.
Thus the only way to say "against the world" with these words is *contra mundum*.

Changing the case changes meaning (and sometimes removes meaning altogether):

> *Anum mundi video.* — I see the anus of the world.
>   *Anum mundum video.* — I see the world and I think it is an anus.

The exact translation of the second one depends on context.